# Why pbuilder couldn't find a directory?

Tags: linux, pbuilder

I have following log using pbuilder:

```
user@comp:~/PROSTOR/pkg-csp$ sudo pbuilder create --configfile /tmp/lastrc --buildplace /var/cache/pbuilder/alse47-arm64/alse47-arm64.cow --mirror https://dl.astralinux.ru/astra/stable/4.7_arm/repository-main --distribution 4.7_arm --no-targz --extrapackages 'cowdancer pbuilder fakeroot quilt python devscripts eatmydata procps locales  cowdancer'
[sudo] password for user: 
W: /root/.pbuilderrc does not exist
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_PAPER = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_TIME = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LANG = "ru_RU.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("ru_RU.UTF-8").
E: Directory /var/cache/pbuilder/alse47-arm64/alse47-arm64.cow does not exist
```

here is /tmp/lastrc https://gist.github.com/iva-nova-e-katerina/46b9e5ae4cbb55a3ec45d5327e22c0b3

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `/var/cache/pbuilder/alse47-arm64/alse47-arm64.cow` exist?

Comment: @StephenKitt cat: /var/cache/pbuilder/alse47-arm64/alse47-arm64.cow: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

`--buildplace` needs to point to an existing directory. Either you need to create `/var/cache/pbuilder/alse47-arm64/alse47-arm64.cow`, or you need to change `--buildplace` to point somewhere else.

Since your `lastrc` includes

```
BUILDPLACE=/var/cache/pbuilder/alse47-arm64/build
```

you could also drop the `--buildplace` option entirely.

`alse47-arm64.cow` sounds like it was supposed to be a `cowbuilder` directory, you might want to use that instead.